# Why does the window title say "gnome-calculator" and not Calculator?

Tags: calculator, gnome-calculator

I found the following inconsistency with gnome-calculator 3.22.0 on Ubuntu 16.10. Why does the window title not say "Calculator" as in the top bar?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a regression since in 16.04 it appears to be "Calculator"

[image]

This change probably is caused by some kind of localization problems. I checked out the code for `gnome-calculator` on Github:

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-calculator/blob/bbb3f2afc64ffa45d90d73571cedd51df5c2d27b/src/gnome-calculator.vala#L80

This line is:

```
current_window.set_title (_("Calculator"));
```

This means the title should be "Calculator" unless the "get text" library returns an alternative string name. I walked the git history back that hasn't changed in ages although the code has had the damn variable names renamed about 5 times in the last year.

Comment: But why? I don't understand the reason behind this move.

Comment: Software regressions aren't intentional they are caused by a lack of testing / quality assurance. In this case `gnome-calculator` may have made a change or localization layers outside of that application responsible for providing the word "Calculator" in the local language.  I will update my answer with some info for fun just to see how deep this goes.

Comment: Detective work updated.

Comment: Strange they seem to be having issues with this and keep committing the same code over and over: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=768432

Comment: I've looked at their git history and bug reports and they seem to be going in a circle unaware they are patching the same lines of code over and over to do the same thing. I personally never communicate with GNOME developers because it's been a waste of time in the past, but you are welcome to communicate to them they are in groundhogs day. My guess is they have a new developer every few months who picks up `gnome-calculator` as some "gnome passage of right" to earn his karma.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! To summarise, this is not a problem on my side but something that needs to be fixed upstream, correct?

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. I looked at their setup and in all versions of 3.0+ of gnome-calculator they use translations to set the window dialog. Basically in code I don't see the problem you have or the bugs they show reported in their bugzilla. Like I said in every version of the software the translation is used and would otherwise default to `Calculator`. So yes the problem is likely upstream I just can't tell you where. For debugging purposes you may want to try changing your language to another language (like Spanish) and see what it does.